# How to pass JSON array of objects as a parameter to ARRAY_CONTAINS function using SQL API

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

My Cosmos DB SQL query includes the following call to the the `ARRAY_CONTAINS` function:

```
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@targetActions, {'aid': c.id, 'at': atil.actionType }, true)
```

I need to use the following JSON array as the `@targetActions` parameter:

```
[
  {
    "aid": "vdb-rc-vote-16375",
    "at": "cast-rc-vote"
  },
  {
    "aid": "vdb-rc-vote-16312",
    "at": "cast-rc-vote"
  },
  {
    "aid": "vdb-rc-vote-16692",
    "at": "cast-rc-vote"
  }
]
```

I use the following code to set the parameter on my query definition:

```
myQueryDefinition.WithParameter("@targetActions", targetActions);
```

I tried the following for the `targetActions` value

- `JArray`
- `string`
- `IEnumerable<TargetActionType>` where `TargetActionType` is a .NET class with the same properties (`aid` and `at`) that are in the JSON objects.

My query does not return the expected result with any of the above.  However, it works fine if I hard-code the JSON in the query as follows:

```
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(
[
  {
    "aid": "vdb-rc-vote-16375",
    "at": "cast-rc-vote"
  },
  {
    "aid": "vdb-rc-vote-16312",
    "at": "cast-rc-vote"
  },
  {
    "aid": "vdb-rc-vote-16692",
    "at": "cast-rc-vote"
  }
]
, {'aid': c.id, 'at': atil.actionType }, true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test,`JArray` is ok,you can try again.

Below is my test code:

```
string sqlQueryText = "SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(@targetActions, {'aid': c.id, 'at': c.at }, true)";
JObject jo1 = new JObject { { "aid", "vdb-rc-vote-16375" },{ "at", "cast-rc-vote" } };
JObject jo2 = new JObject { { "aid", "vdb-rc-vote-16312" }, { "at", "cast-rc-vote" } };
JObject jo3 = new JObject { { "aid", "vdb-rc-vote-16692" }, { "at", "cast-rc-vote" } };
JArray targetActions = new JArray();
targetActions.Add(jo1);
targetActions.Add(jo2);
targetActions.Add(jo3);
QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText).WithParameter("@targetActions", targetActions);
FeedIterator queryResultSetIterator = this.container.GetItemQueryStreamIterator(queryDefinition);
while (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    using (ResponseMessage response = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync())
    {
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(response.Content);
        string responseContentAsString = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseContentAsString);
    }
}
```

Here is result:

```
{"_rid":"R-5RALZpDGQ=","Documents":[{"id":"vdb-rc-vote-16375","at":"cast-rc-vote"}],"_count":1}
```

This is my document of cosmos db:

```
{
    "id": "vdb-rc-vote-16375",
    "at": "cast-rc-vote"
}
```

Hope this can help you:).

Comment: Thanks for confirming that `JArray` was the way to go.  I had some other problem with my query.  After solving that, the query works with `JArray` as the parameter type to `.WithParameter`.